# Files/Media Not getting Access publicly with URL in Codeignitator

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-permissions

I'm using a Codeignitator application named Perfex CRM and I'm having an issue to access its photos/files

when I'm logged in web panel I can access photos and all files with URL encryption
[image]

**My question is I want to access these files/Media publicly with out login to web panel
but when I visit this URL without login it gives me this error**

[image]

more to it i also tried to access files directy from folder `https://support.two.com.pk/uploads/tasks/2020082011243932x32.png` but it still gives same error 404.

What i have tried for this to access these file publically.

1. i have tried to change permission from htaccess file
2. i have tried to change all folder permission from 755 to 777 and also files permission from 644 to 777 but no luck.

Comment: you say it's a Codeigniter application, well then it follows these rules: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html?#uri-segments. Anyway your question is unclear/needs more details, you should add a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in order to get an answer

Comment: I'm not able to access media files using link.

Comment: *1. i have tried to change permission from htaccess file*, how does that look like at the moment?

Comment: https://support.two.com.pk/uploads/tasks/2020082011243932x32.png

you can check this link the file is exist in folder but it's saying 404 error

Comment: sorry I'm not clicking any links...

Comment: ok then u can guide why this not giving 404 error ..even though file exist in folder

Comment: edit your question and add your current .htaccess file and describe how you have *tried to change permission from htaccess file*

Comment: i just remove all data from htaccess file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution I have removed encryption folder and encryption id from config.php file and then cleared cache folder all set. working fine to me.